# Do Any Changes to the Maven Java Project Have to Do the Maven "Package or Install" to Run in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2

We are currently migrating to Maven Java project on Eclipse, previously we just build project based "`Web Dynamic Project`" which is running smoothly, every changes to the code we just do `Run as > Run on Server` (Automatic build enabled), nothing else.

My question is, do we have to `Run as > Maven Install, Refresh, Run as > Run on Server` every single **changes** on our code ? 
If the answer is yes, what a nightmare to us ?

Comment: Is it a web application? so, changing the web files does not need to restart server.

Comment: Yes it is, and then what about if the changes is in java files ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use JRebel.
Check this link for more information:
https://www.jrebel.com/products/jrebel/quickstart/eclipse